# bindService(): do I have to protect against onServiceConnected() never coming

Tags: android, android-service

Android's Context.bindService() is asynchronous. Even if it returns `true`, the IBinder is not available right away. You give it a ServiceConnection object and the framework calls it back. That's how it's supposed to be, at least.

Did anyone ever encounter a situation that bindService() returns `true`, but the onServiceConnected() call never comes? Is it a condition I have to account for and protect against?

The service I'm going to use is the in-app billing.

Answer (score 0):

If the service that you bind to is running within the same process as the client (i.e. a local service), then there are no practical reason for onServiceConnected not to be called if bindService returns true. If the service is running in a remote process, then there is at least one condition that you should handle even if bindService returns true: if the remote process crashes, then you will get onServiceDisconnected, and then onServiceConnected again when the system has restarted the service again, and that might take a while.

You should be able to trust the system that if bind returns true, and no security exceptions are thrown, you should get onServiceConnected within a reasonable time.

Comment: In-app billing is remote. It runs in `com.android.vending` AKA the Market app.